# Simple pendulum as Hamiltonian system

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am unable to understand how to put the equation of the simple pendulum in the generalized coordinates and generalized momenta in order to check if it is or not a Hamiltonian System.

Having

$$E_T = E_k + E_u = \frac{1}{2}ml^2\dot\theta^2 + mgl(1-cos\theta)$$

How can I found what are the $p$ and $q$ for $H(q,p)$ in order to check that the following holds, i.e. the system is a Hamiltonian system.

$$\frac{dq}{dt}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{-\partial H}{\partial q}$$

Answer (score 6):

The Lagrangian is
$${\cal L}=\frac{1}{2}ml^2\dot{\theta}^2-mgl(1-\cos\theta).$$
The conjugate momentum is
$$p_\theta=\frac{\partial{\cal L}}{\partial\dot{\theta}}=ml^2\dot{\theta}$$
and so the Hamiltonian is
$${\cal H}=\sum_q \dot{q}p_q-{\cal L}=\frac{1}{2}ml^2\dot{\theta}^2+mgl(1-\cos\theta)=\frac{p_\theta^2}{2ml^2}+mgl(1-\cos\theta).$$

Comment: What does $p_\theta$ mean? what does $p_q$ mean?

Comment: Could you develop more after you write $\cal H = \sum - \cal L$?

Comment: As stated, $p_\theta$ is the conjugate momentum to $\theta$. What kind of development are you looking for? It's a substitution of the  second equation into the third equation. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#As_a_reformulation_of_Lagrangian_mechanics)

Comment: I am just trying to prove the system is a Hamiltonian system, but if I take the partial derivatives I don't get $\dot q = \partial H / \partial p$ and $\dot p = \partial H / \partial q$, I guess I am doing something wrong.

Comment: In the Hamiltonian you wrote, what would be $q$, would it be $\theta$? If so, I'm getting $\partial H / \partial p = \dot \theta$ and $dq/dt = mgl sin\theta \cdot \dot \theta$ which are not the same, therefore not a Hamiltonian, but of course it is, so I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, the coordinate is $\theta$. $\partial H/\partial p=\dot\theta$ doesn't make sense: you need to express $H$ as a function of the coordinate and the momentum, without reference to the time derivative of the coordinate.